# Why the move assignment is not called here

Tags: c++

I cant get move semantics and rvalues,I will post code first and then ask :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Spred{
    public:
        Spred(int siz=10):sz{siz},ptrtoint{new int[siz]},c{0} {cout<<"Constructor()"<<endl;}

        ~Spred(){delete [] ptrtoint;cout<<"Destructor()"<<endl;}
        Spred(Spred& src){
            ptrtoint=new int[src.sz];
            for(int i=0;i<src.c;i++)
                ptrtoint[i]=src.ptrtoint[i];
            sz=src.sz;c=src.c;
            cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
        }
        Spred& operator=(Spred &src){
            delete [] ptrtoint;
            sz=src.sz;
            c=src.c;
            ptrtoint=new int[sz];
            for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
                ptrtoint[i]=src.ptrtoint[i];
            return *this;
            cout<<"Copy assignment"<<endl;
        }
        Spred(Spred&& src){
            ptrtoint=new int[src.sz];
            for(int i=0;i<src.c;i++)
                ptrtoint[i]=src.ptrtoint[i];
            sz=src.sz;c=src.c;
            delete [] src.ptrtoint;
            src.ptrtoint=nullptr;
            src.sz=0;src.c=0;
            cout<<"Move constructor"<<endl;
        }
        Spred& operator=(Spred&& src){
            delete [] ptrtoint;
            ptrtoint=new int[src.sz];
            sz=src.sz;c=src.c;
            for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
                ptrtoint[i]=src.ptrtoint[i];
            delete [] src.ptrtoint;
            src.ptrtoint=nullptr;
            src.sz=0;src.c=0;
            return *this;
            cout<<"Move assignment"<<endl;
        }
        void push_back(int a){
            ptrtoint[c++]=a;
        }
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,Spred &src){
            for(int i=0;i<src.c;i++){
                os<<src.ptrtoint[i]<<" ";
            }
            return os;
        }
    private:
        int *ptrtoint;
        int sz;int c;
};
Spred createObject(){
    return Spred(15);
}
int main()
{

    Spred s;
    s=createObject();
    return 0;
}
```

I have concrete question ,why the Move assignment is not called here when I invoke the createObject function,isn`t the object returned from the function Rvalue,if it is Rvalue it should call the move assignment in the class?

Comment: @AlexFarber RVO won't apply since it is an assignment and not an initialization, will it?

Comment: try s=std::move(createObject());

Comment: And what is called? Copy assignment? Nothing?

Comment: Just the constructor and the destructors of the two objects,the local one and the one in the main fucntion.

Answer (score 4):

The move assignment operator is indeed being called. However, in `operator=(Spred&&)`, you are calling `cout` after `return *this;`. After changing it to

```
Spred& operator=(Spred&& src){
            delete [] ptrtoint;
            ptrtoint=new int[src.sz];
            sz=src.sz;c=src.c;
            for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
                ptrtoint[i]=src.ptrtoint[i];
            delete [] src.ptrtoint;
            src.ptrtoint=nullptr;
            src.sz=0;src.c=0;
            cout<<"Move assignment"<<endl;
            return *this;
        }
```

you will see the output

```
Constructor()
Constructor()
Move assignment
Destructor()
Destructor()
```

as you expect.